# Fullscreen API not working on Chrome/iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, video

I am trying to display a video in fullscreen when the user clicks on a link/button. This is working fine in desktop but not working well on iPad using chrome.

According to this http://caniuse.com/fullscreen there are some restrictions but i can't find chrome/ios on that table.

If somebody tells me that it's an operative system restriction I will really appreciate a link from a nice source.

Here's some code:

HTML:

```
<video id="video1" width="420" controls>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg" />Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>

<button onclick="PlayFunction();">PLAY</button>
```

Javascript:

```
 function PlayFunction()
{
        launchFullScreen(document.getElementById("video1")); // any individual element);
    $("#video1")[0].play();

}function launchFullScreen(element) {  
      if (element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {

        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {

        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else {

        alert("no cai en ningun lado");
    }
}
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9aSjn/16/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this link http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/chrome-ios-android-4-1-jelly-bean-html5 :

> That’s is because Chrome for iOS is not Chrome. What?? It has a
>   Chrome-style UI, onmibox, search by voice and it has Chrome synching.
>   However, the rendering and execution engine are not Chrome.
>
> I called them pseudo-browsers and you can see my opinion and a good
>   discussion on the comments area in my previous post. So Chrome for iOS
>   is in fact using the iOS Web View that share most of the code with
>   Safari.
>
> The User Agent that Chrome for iOS is using is the Safari one with one
>   addition: “CriOS” (Chrome for iOS I guess). There is no “Chrome” word
>   inside the User Agent, so if you are doing something special for
>   Chrome, you are safe and it’s not going to be executed on Chrome on
>   iOS.

Conclusion, when you are using Chrome on iOS you are using Safari, and that's why it doesn't appear in the caniuse table.