# document.documentElement requestFullscreen - undefined is not an object, mobile ios

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-dom

Following [this tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptfullscreenapi.shtml) I wrote this react component (simplified to only show the problem):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class HeaderImages extends Component {

  //usage: getreqfullscreen().call(targetelement) // open full screen on targetelement
  getreqfullscreen = () => {
    var root = document.documentElement;
    return (
      root.requestFullscreen ||
      root.webkitRequestFullscreen ||
      root.mozRequestFullScreen ||
      root.msRequestFullscreen
    );
  };

  //usage: getexitfullscreen.call(document) //always pass document into it
  getexitfullscreen = () => {
    return (
      document.exitFullscreen ||
      document.webkitExitFullscreen ||
      document.mozCancelFullScreen ||
      document.msExitFullscreen
    );
  };

  getfullscreenelement = () => {
    return (
      document.fullscreenElement ||
      document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
      document.mozFullScreenElement ||
      document.msFullscreenElement
    );
  };

  toggleFullScreen = e => {
    if (this.getfullscreenelement() == null) {
      // if browser is currently not in full screen
      this.getreqfullscreen().call(e.target);
    } else {
      this.getexitfullscreen().call(document);
    }
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <img
          src={url}
          className="header-image"
          alt="project-screenshot"
          onClick={this.toggleFullScreen.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HeaderImages;
```

What I would like to happen is for the image to go full screen when clicked. This works in every desktop browser I tested with, but when I open the app on the ios mobile versions of chrome and safari I get the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this.getreqfullscreen().call')

Pointing to the line:
`this.getreqfullscreen().call(e.target);`

The stack trace is pointing to `react-dom`.

I have trouble figuring out what the error means and how to fix it - the `onClick` function passes the DOM node correctly and `document.documentElement` seems ok as well.

The [Element.requestFullscreen() specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen) show the feature as available on mobile chrome.

Is there an alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

<del>I think you just have a typo on : `webkitRequestFullscreen` try `webkitRequestFullScreen` and `msRequestFullscreen` to `msRequestFullScreen` (screen => Screen)</del>

Edit : i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602467/fullscreen-api-not-working-on-chrome-ios) that chrome on ios is using safari and isn't supporting fullscreen API so you may need a [polyfill](https://github.com/neovov/Fullscreen-API-Polyfill).

Comment: Tried, and does not work. Also if I break the `root.requestFullscreen` return the error is different - then the app will return `Uncaught TypeError: _this.getreqfullscreen(...).call is not a function`

Comment: @Dyo: Have you checked the link (http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptfullscreenapi.shtml) he has given?

Comment: `webkitRequestFullscreen` and `msRequestFullscreen` are proper.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
$("#fullsize").click(function (){
    polyfill();
});
function polyfill() {
    var interesting = document.getElementById("interesting");

    // Check if this browser support the fullscreen API
    if (typeof document.fullscreenEnabled !== undefined) {

        // Register a click handler for the <div>
        interesting.addEventListener("click", function() {

            // Toggle fullscreen
            if (document.fullscreenElement) {
                document.exitFullscreen();
            } else {
                this.requestFullscreen();
            }

        }, false);

    }
```